# Using Prepared Statement to get results from Oracle Database where column size is char[2]

Tags: java, oracle

I am using Prepared Statement to get results from Oracle Database in my java code. One of the fields (x) in my table is char(2).
For this field, I am passing the parameter as follows:

```
setString (1, "1")
```

However in this case, the query doesn’t return any results. The table has rows with x=1. 
I also get results via my code if I hardcode the value in the query e.g.

```
select * 
from abc where x=1
```

I am facing this issue only when x is of length 1. E.g.
`setString(1, "47")` returns the correct values in my java code which match the rows in database where x=47.

If I pass `setString(1, "1 ")` i.e. a space after 1, I get the correct values.
But `setString(1, " 1")` i.e. a space before 1, doesn’t give any values.

Please guide me if this is a known issue with Prepared Statement or I am doing something incorrectly. How do I address the issue.

Comment: "*How do I address the issue*" - very simple: do not use the `char` type. It has absolutely no advantages whatsoever over `varchar2` but a number of disadvantages (and the problem you have right now, is one of them)

Comment: The problem is that fields with a CHAR datatype are right-padded with blanks to the declared width of the field, so `"1"` is stored in the database as `"1 "`, with a trailing blank. Thus, if you search for `"1"` it's not there. Instead, look for `"1 "`. But @a_horse_with_no_name's suggestion is best - don't ever use CHAR. Change your tables to use VARCHAR2.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Following are my questions:
1. I dont have the option to change the datatype of column as it is a legacy application. Is there any other way to address the issue?
2. If the value stored for char[2] datatype as "1 ", then how does the following query work in SQL Developer?
select * from abc where x='1'